# Can I customize Angular global error handler to take more than just an error parameter?

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, rxjs

Following https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler I can override the global error handler to do stuff with an error object, and I like the way I can just declare my own global error handler and import it anywhere I need it.

But with RxJS I use `catchError(this.handleError(my, params, go, here))` alot.

I'd like to globalize my `handleError()` method, and incorporate it in my global error handler. But it doesn't look like that's technically possible.

This is what my `handleError` method does, which in combination with RxJS's `catchError` handles the error by (1) logging it to a logger (2) logging it to the console and (3) returning a dummy `Observable` so that the RxJS call can complete smoothly.

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  public handleError<T>(
    error: HttpErrorResponse, operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    var errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ProgressEvent) {
      errorMessage = `Client error occurred: ${error.message}`;
    } else {
      errorMessage = `Adam's error ${error.status}: ${error.message}`;
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    this.messageService.add(`${operation} failed: ${errorMessage}`);
    return of(result as T);
  }

}
```

How can I do this as a global error handler? Or should I take a different approach? I know I could create an *"error service"* to hold my generic `handleError()`, and inject it everywhere like every other service, but that seems clunky.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to get your classes out of Angular context, you could create a custom operator for RxJS. This is not really a solution to your issue but rather a workaround : use it in last resort, if no-one else provides a solution :

```
export function handleCustomError<T>(...args) {
  // Out of Angular's context, you should not have a dependency in your constructor
  const errorHandler = new GlobalErrorHandler();
  return catchError<T>(errorHandler.handleError(...args));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the handleError method returns void. Here you want to return an Observable using the method of().

Secondly, you should take into consideration that handleError method in the GlobalErrorHandler will be executed not only for HttpErrorResponse´s, but also for any Error raised in your app (like a division by zero, for instance). Why would return and Observable when a division by zero or any other unforseen error occurs in your app?

I think your approach is not correct. If you want to catch an error (and I will assume) coming from your API Server just to log it and return a default value so that your app will not break or anything, I would use an http-interceptor. You can catch any error there, perform some actions (logging) and pass through a custom value again to the chain.

[Http interceptor interface](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)

[Logging with http interceptors](https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-logging-http-interceptor)

[Intercepting http requests](https://juristr.com/blog/2017/08/intercept-http-requests-in-angular/)

Let mw know how it went. I can give more guidance otherwise.

Best,
Max.